# Refresh Token & Logout using azure-mobile-apps cordova client

Tags: javascript, cordova, azure, azure-mobile-services, azure-ad-b2c

I'm developing `mobile app` using **azure-mobile-apps cordova** client. I followed  this https://cgillum.tech/2016/08/10/app-service-auth-and-azure-ad-b2c-part-2/ to get refresh tokens.

I'm sending id_token in header.

```
var token = window.localStorage.getItem("token");
var appUrl = https://Mobile****.azurewebsites.net;
var url = appUrl + "/.auth/refresh";
$http.get(url, {
    headers: {
        'X-ZUMO-AUTH': token
    }
})
.then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

> Response : 401 Unauthorized. IDX10500: Signature validation failed.
>   Unable to resolve SecurityKeyIdentifier...

I compared my secret keys in Resource explorer and Tenant ->Application -> Keys.

Both are same.
I also want to ask about logout, can we send same as above at this endpoint `/.auth/logout`.

Comment: Hi @devangi, any update?

Comment: Hi  sorry for delay. Yes, I want to ask about these tokens  (mobileServiceAuthenticationToken, id_token & refresh_token)?   Expire time , id_token & refresh_token are available through /.auth/me endpoint.
My observation is that within 1 hour , even if you genenarete any no of mobileServiceAuthenticationToken (using /.auth/refresh), but expire time will be same (at /.auth/me). 
After an hour if you call /.auth/refresh with old token, it will give 500 internal server error. So What is lifetime of mobileServiceAuthentication token , id_token & refresh_token ?

Comment: About how to keep the user perpetually logged in you can refer to [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41310757/mobileservices-web-js-unauthorized-api-call).

Comment: Hi my basic understanding is that `mobileServiceAuthenticationToken` expires at 1hour. To refresh this token , we will call /.auth/refresh. Is it suffice to get updated token from B2C and user will be alive for more period like 1 day ?? And we can cross verify updated expire time from /.auth/me. Am  I correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the `/.auth/refresh` to work, like @mattchenderson mentioned in earlier post, please make sure `client.currentUser.mobileServiceAuthenticationToken` is passed in the `X-ZUMO-AUTH` header.

For log out, you can use logout function of [build-in SDK](https://azure.github.io/azure-mobile-apps-js-client/MobileServiceClient.html#logout).
Please try the following code to log a user out of the Mobile App.

```
client.logout().then(function () {
    window.cookies.clear(function() {
        $state.go('index');
    });        
});
```

**Note:** the web view has stored the login info in cookies, and the next time you log in via the authentication provider, the browser will automatically read the cookies and finish the login flow. So please make sure the cookies are cleared when logging out. I used [Phonegap-Cookies-Plugin](https://github.com/bez4pieci/Phonegap-Cookies-Plugin) to do this job. Please note that it works for both PhoneGap and Cordova.

Comment: Thank you for response, it was resolved for both sign out & refresh token.

Answer (score 1):

The token submitted in the `X-ZUMO-AUTH` header should always be an App Service token, not the AAD ID token. This token would have been obtained using one of the client.login() methods from the [Mobile Apps SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-cordova-how-to-use-client-library#a-nameauthahow-to-authenticate-users). You can access this token from the client object (via `client.currentUser.mobileServiceAuthenticationToken`).