# MobileServices.web.js unauthorized api call

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-mobile-services, winjs

When I leave my WinJS app dormant for a while and then come back to it, and i click on a button, for some reason my calls to my backend aren't working.

I get an "Unauthorized" error from the server.

How do I modify the invokeApi so that it reauthenticates the user or something?

Does anybody have any experience using mobileservices.web.js and how to keep the end user perpetually logged in without having to reauthenticate themselves?

Thankyou.

```
client.invokeApi("getTopForumsTotal", {
    method: "post"
}).then(function (results) {
    // do something
}, function (error) {
    WinJS.log(error);
});
```

I use winjs mobileService to authenticate the user.

```
client.login("microsoftaccount").done(function (results) {
    // Create a credential for the returned user.
    credential = new Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordCredential("myapp", results.userId, results.mobileServiceAuthenticationToken);
    vault.add(credential);

    completeDispatcher();
}, function (error) {
    WinJS.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    errorDispatcher(error);
});
```

and this is what I use to refresh the end users token.

```
client._request("GET", "/.auth/refresh", null, null, {
    accept: "application/json",
    "ZUMO-API-VERSION": "2.0.0"
}, [], (error, response) => {
    if (!error) {
        var userObject = JSON.parse(response.responseText)

        if (userObject.authenticationToken) {
            client.currentUser.mobileServiceAuthenticationToken = userObject.authenticationToken;

            testCall().done(function (success) {
                if (success) {
                    credential = new Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordCredential("myapp", userObject.user.userId, userObject.authenticationToken);
                    vault.add(credential);
                    authenticated = true;
                    completeDispatcher();
                }
                else errorDispatcher('testCall API does not exist');
            });
        }
        else errorDispatcher('no authentication token returned');
    }
    else errorDispatcher(error);
});
```

Comment: Do you use WinJS to create Windows/Windows Phone application? How do you auth your mobile App? Please give more information to help us better understanding your issue.

Comment: I have updated my answer.  The problem I am experiencing is when to call the refresh token routine.  The points where it fails is when making api calls to the server using the client object.  e.g. client.invokeApi, table calls, or client._request calls.  These calls fail if the authentication token expires, so the refresh has to be called before that.  How do I set it up so that I can refresh the token if the users machine has been idle and they return?

Comment: About how to use Refresh Tokens I would recommend you refer to [this blog post](https://shellmonger.com/2016/04/13/30-days-of-zumo-v2-azure-mobile-apps-day-7-refresh-tokens/).

Comment: Hi aaron thanks for the link.  I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of wrapping a promise around every API call I just incorporated an idle routine on the client that refreshes the user token when they return to the app as well as refreshes the token every 59 seconds that they are idle.

So for all intense and purposes they will always have an valid token or perpetual state.

```
$(document).idle({
    onIdle: function () {
        // refresh user token
        if (User.Person !== null)
            User.Person.reauthenticate().done();
    },
    onActive: function () {
        // when the user returns refresh their token 1 more time
        if (User.Person !== null)
            User.Person.reauthenticate().done();
    },
    idle: 59000, // 59 seconds
    recurIdleCall: true // will keep refreshing every 59 seconds
});
```

https://github.com/kidh0/jquery.idle